# Rails query, require all conditions in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models, both associated with each other through has_many through.

I can query the model and filter based on its associated records:

`Car.includes(:equipment).where(equipment: { id: [1, 2, 3] })`

The problem is that I want to require all of those records, rather than requiring just one of them.

Is there a way to build a query that requires all of the values in the array (the [1, 2, 3] from the above example).

In other words, I'd like to query for all cars that have all three equipment (ids of 1, 2 and 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an `id_ary` like `[1,2,3]`, how about something like:

```
id_ary.each_with_object(Car.includes(:equipment)) do |id, scope|
  scope.where(equipment: {id: id})
end
```

Looping like that should `and` your `where` conditions, I believe.

Comment: Works great!  Thanks.